# Full width navigation

Tags: html, css, structure, zurb-foundation

I'm hoping this may be a quick fix. I've been staring at this for ages and I hope that a fresh pair of eyes will be able to see whats wrong straight away!

Problem:

1. The navigation at the bottom needs to be full width of the page. I want it to strech the width of page without and white space around the edges.

**PLEASE BE AWARE THAT I'VE ONLY STARTED CODING THIS FOR 768PX AND BELOW.**

http://jsfiddle.net/5e7kp/

**Navigation:**

```
<footer class="row small-12 columns clearfix">
    <nav id="footnav">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="About">About</a>
            </li>


            <li>
                <a href="#" title="Work">Work</a>
            </li>


            <li>
                <a href="#" title="Contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>


    <p>&copy; 2014 hsudfapsdif</p>
</footer>

nav #footnav {
    margin: 0;
}
nav ul li {
    position:relative;
    margin-left:3.333333333333%
}

nav ul li a {
    display:block;
    text-transform:lowercase;
    padding:2em 3.333333333333%;
    padding:1.2em 6.25%;
    font-size:16px;
    background:#121314 url(../img/arrow.png) no-repeat 93.5% 50%;
    border-bottom:1px solid #222
}

nav a:link,nav a:visited {
    color:#666;
    font-weight:700;
    text-decoration:none;
    -webkit-transition:all .25s linear;
    transition:color .25s linear
}

nav a:hover,nav a:active {
    color:#ccc
}

nav ul li.current a:link,nav ul li.current a:visited,nav ul li.current a:hover,nav ul li.current a:active {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#111
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/5e7kp/2/)**

```
<div class="row small-2 columns large-2 columns clearfix btnWrap">
    <span class="btn">Read More</span> 
</div>

    body {
       margin: 0;
    }

    .btnWrap{
        text-align: right;
    }

    .btn{
       padding:10px 20px;
    }

    nav ul{
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
    }

    nav ul li{
       margin-left:0; // Remove the left margin
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunatly the navigation still has whitespace around it. and the button hasn't moved. thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Might be I did not understand your question, you can check the updated  demo link.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to take care of the button issue. Check out these two options...

**Option 1: Wrap a new div**

```
<div class="align-right">
  <div class="row small-2 columns large-2 columns btn clearfix">Read More</div>
</div>

.align-right {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

**Option 2: Add float and margin**

```
.btn {
  -webkit-border-radius:28;
  -moz-border-radius:28;
  border-radius:28px;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:12px;
  background:#00A2D2;
  padding:10px 20px;
  text-decoration:none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

As for the nav, how about just adding `width: 100%;` to the `#footnav`? Maybe I'm not sure what you're asking exactly...

Comment: Excellent, the button worked, thank you. In regards to the navigation i just want each <li> to span the whole width of the page. Just like the header at the top. does that make sense? thanks

Comment: Difficult to help without seeing the real thing... Try adding `margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0;` and/or `padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0;` and/or `width: 100%` to `nav ul li`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing  or editing it's CSS properties? Try removing  and replace it with a row instead...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add two rules to your existing markup.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

nav ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

You also had a left margin set on the list items. Remove that

http://jsfiddle.net/michaelburtonray/5e7kp/3/